# В чем суть api?

Tags: php, json, api

Если я правильно понимаю, в api запросы к сайту практически не отличаются от обычных запросов, разница заключается лишь в том что в api запрос осуществляет другое приложение, а не пользователь и в ответ возвращается стандартное для многих приложений json-представление(массив)? Тогда к чему такая отдельная и обширная область в программировании - API?

Comment: Ану ка дай ссылку на это "обширную область"

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под `обычные запросы`?

Comment: @Manitikyl, вероятно тс подразумевал рендер страницы на стороне сервера и последующий ее возврат пользователю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет никакой обширной области.

Есть, скажем так, некие практики и подходы, которые применяются для разработки API, но по сути кроме интерфейса взаимодействия с клиентом ничем API не отличается.

API возвращает тебе не страницу с HTML-вёрсткой (отрендеренную сервером), а лысый JSON (XML, и т.д.) с данными, которые ты принимаешь где-то (фронтенд, мобильное приложение, SPA, и т.д.) и обрабатываешь.

Comment: апи по вашему не может вернуть html ?

Comment: @teran API это обмен голыми данными. Если протокол обмена данными представлен в виде HTML, то да, он может возвращать HTML, хотя это уже будет XML.

Comment: @teran может конечно. Всё зависит от Ваших требований к API.